# Regex - matching a beginning and closing tag

Tags: regex

I have a data file I am trying to validate with a VBScript regex object.

Data:

```
01THAILAND       000004
08 000004 05
```

Regex pattern :  `^01.{15}[0-9]{6}|^08 [0-9]{6} [0-9]{2}.`

How do I setup my pattern to parse the line beginning 08 as valid if it has the same code '000004' as the first line? Other data lines exist between these two items and the code will not always be '000004'! The only things that will remain specific are the 2 character line identifier and the format.

Comment: What's wrong with what you already have? It seems like that would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Pure regexes won't cut it, but that's probably not hat you're using anyway.

The widespread naming for this sort of thing is called "backreferencing", and allows you to include part of the regex currently being matched against inside the pattern itself.  The usual syntax, inherited from `sed`, is `\1` to reference the first capturing parentheses of the regex.

So in your example it'd look something like:

```
^01.{15}\([0-9]{6}\)
.*
^08 \1 [0-9]{2}.
```

Do note that you're not matching for single lines any more, but for the whole group.  (To match single lines, you'd really need to remember the original code and include it explicitly in your terminating regex.)  So you'll need to make sure your regex engine is capable of multiline matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\n` as a backreference where n is the index of the captured group. Demo:

```
str = "01THAILAND       000004" & vbNewLine & "08 000004 05"

Set re = new regexp
re.Pattern = "\d+\w+ +(\d+)\s+\d+ \1 \d+"    ' \1 is the back reference
re.Global = true

msgbox re.Test(str)
```

Ninja edit: your pattern would be something like `^01.{15}([0-9]{6})\s{1,2}08 \1 [0-9]{2}`